# Laravel, Edit/Update specific fields via the same update method in the controller

Tags: laravel, crud

I have a form by which user can update his data (name, lastname, **status** ...)

In another page I like to have a form by which user just can edit and update the **status** field and keep other fields unchanged
Should I create another update function in the UserController? Since the current one requires existence of the other fields in the form.

if I need a new handler how should I route the form action to that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for another update function, let's say `updateStatus` in your UserController. You will use a specific validator within this function.

If you have in your User Model some validation rules like this:

```
public static $rulesUpdate = [
    'name'     => 'required',
    'lastname' => 'required',
    'status'   => 'required',
];
```

I would do in your `updateStatus` function:

```
$status = Input::get('status');
$validatorStatus = Validator::make(['status' => $status], ['status' => User::$rulesUpdate['status']]);
if ($validatorStatus->passes()) {
    // Your logic here, maybe something like this
    $user->status = $status;
    $user->save();
}
```

The nice thing here is that you use the **same** validation rules.

Create a new route for method, something like:

```
Route::put('/users/status', ['before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'UsersController@putStatus']);
```

Comment: thank you, and you pointed the nice thing about same validation rules.